# how to display an input value using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple calculator with vanilla.js. However, I am having difficulty on creating the functionalities. I can get to display the number when click, but not when I click multiple times or delete that value on click. i tried addeventlistener but i always get an Type Error "addeventlistener not a function".. if you have any recommended website or tutorial to better understand vanilla, please point it.. thanks in advance

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

var clear = document.querySelector('#delete');

var backSpace = document.querySelector('.backspace');

var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.input-btn');

var operators = document.querySelector('.operator-right');

var equalBtn = document.querySelector('.equal-btn');

function insert(num) {
  result.value = num;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calc">
    <div class="result">
      <input class="input-btn__result" id="result" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <input class="clear" id="delete" type="button" onClick="clear()" value="C">
      <input class="backspace" type="button" name="" value="<">
      <input class="input-btn__divide operator-right" type="button" name="" value="/">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(1)" value="1">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(2)" name="" value="2">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(3)" name="" value="3">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="*">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(4)" name="" value="4">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(5)" name="" value="5">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(6)" name="" value="6">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="+">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(7)" name="" value="7">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(8)" name="" value="8">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(9)" name="" value="9">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="-">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert('.')" name="" value=".">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" onClick="insert(0)" name="" value="0">
      <input class="equal-btn" type="button" name="" value="=">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, i did not..

Comment: You should show the code which doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing what you want to do. Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for recommendations on resources for learning vanilla JS (if you google you can find multiple good resources and pick the one you like best). As Alvin already mentioned in his answer, you definitely want to learn more about how to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

This is how I'd do it using your HTML (with one *important exception*: I've eliminated all your `onClick` HTML attributes -- it's best to separate your JavaScript code from your HTML structure):

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result'),
      btns = document.querySelector('div.btns');

/* 
calculandum here is the previous number, 
to be used with the math operation (+, -, /, *) 
*/
let calculandum = '';

// addEventListener to all your buttons
for (let child of btns.children) {
  child.addEventListener('click', insert);
}

function insert(e) { // e is the event; e.target is the HTML element; e.target.value is this element's value
  let btnValue = e.target.value;
  switch (btnValue){
    case 'C':
      result.value = '0';
      calculandum = '';
      break;
    case '<':
      if (result.value) result.value = result.value.slice(0,-1);
      if (result.value === '') result.value = '0';
      break;
    case '*':
      if (result.value) { // result.value will be '' after an operator is clicked, as can be seen in the next lines
        calculandum += result.value + '*';
        result.value = '';
      }
      break;
    case '=':
      calculandum += result.value;
      result.value = eval(calculandum);
      calculandum = '';
      break;
    default:
      result.value === '0' ? result.value = btnValue : result.value += btnValue;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calc">
    <div class="result">
      <input class="input-btn__result" id="result" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <input class="clear" id="delete" type="button" value="C">
      <input class="backspace" type="button" name="" value="<">
      <input class="input-btn__divide operator-right" type="button" name="" value="/">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" value="1">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="2">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="3">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="*">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="4">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="5">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="6">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="+">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="7">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="8">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="9">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="-">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value=".">
      <input class="input-btn" type="button" name="" value="0">
      <input class="equal-btn" type="button" name="" value="=">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work for multiplications, from this example you can code the rest of the operations. You can also note I've eliminated most of your `vars` because they weren't doing anything. One final note is that I'd definitely rethink how you're using classes for your HTML elements. For example, classes should be used for multiple elements, you can use IDs for just one element (so, classes `calc` and `btns` maybe should be IDs).

Comment: Nice effort BUT - This does not work when you click on `=`. Please review your answer.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hi! Thanks for catching a bug, but what's the error you're getting? I'm getting exactly the right result for multiplications (this code only works for multiplications, as I mentioned in the answer). Hmmm but there's an error if you repeatedly hit `=`, I'll fix it

Comment: Seems like when you click `<` and the click `=` you get this error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<<'",`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Oh, true, but I didn't code the script for all buttons, I left that for the OP. I just did an example for multiplications, so he can see how to do it for the rest

Comment: Nice effort - Thanks for contributing :)

Comment: @Mr.J I added the code part for the erase `<` button as well (I figured since it's a bit different from all other buttons you might run into trouble for this one)

Comment: Nice work :) Thumbs Up

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks! Btw, I like your name and your ethos, sometimes people forget that SO is also for newbies and that we should help them as well

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class name for input buttons which for insert function, and then use `addEventListener` to add event.

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

var clear = document.querySelector('#delete');

var backSpace = document.querySelector('.backspace');

var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.input-btn');

var operators = document.querySelector('.operator-right');

var equalBtn = document.querySelector('.equal-btn');

var insertBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.insert-btn');

function insert(e) {
  result.value = e.target.value;
}

for (var i = 0; i < insertBtns.length; i++) {
  insertBtns[i].addEventListener('click', insert);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calc">
    <div class="result">
      <input class="input-btn__result" id="result" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <input class="clear" id="delete" type="button" onClick="clear()" value="C" >
      <input class="backspace" type="button" name="" value="<">
      <input class="input-btn__divide operator-right" type="button" name="" value="/">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button"  value="1">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="2">
      <input class="input-btn insert-bt" type="button" name="" value="3">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="*">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="4">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="5">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="6">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="+">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="7">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="8">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="9">
      <input class="input-btn operator-right" type="button" name="" value="-">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value=".">
      <input class="input-btn insert-btn" type="button" name="" value="0">
      <input class="equal-btn"  type="button" name="" value="=">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're in the right path, but please note that the calculator still isn't working. Shoudln't the `insert` function be `result.value += ...`? And you probably want to handle the case for the `C` button differently (that is, `result.value = '';`)

Comment: There's also no need to create a new class. You can run a for-loop for each child of `document.querySelector('div.btns')`

Comment: Because based on original code, different btns has some other behavior.
I think the best solution is use event delegation.

Comment: And I only show how to let `addEventListener` can work. Not for full logic of the calculator ,  maybe you can provide full calculator logic for the author.

Comment: No, I think you're doing a great work, and it's best not to provide the full code, but to let the OP figure it out by themselves. You're also right that based on the original code the buttons have different behavior, but this could also be handled by the insert function

Comment: You are right, it really can all handle in the insert function. Base on the original code, for author, some btns not contain onClick event, they should not be registered event, too.
So, I just want to use the simple method to focus on onClick event not work.
But I think your point of view can make the calculator to do further implement.

Comment: thanks for both your point. to be honest, i even tried that result.value = ' ' (clear function), but doesn't do anything at all so i left that part for the end. i totally understand for the for-loop, however, by implementing that then i get the default value for result.value which is 0 plus the numbers clicked. if you guys can point a tutorial for the logic.

Comment: @Mr.J you can check my answer if you need a starting place for the code. There are a bunch of online courses for learning JS. freecodecamp and codecademy provide free courses, also edx.org and coursera.org . For learning resources, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) is my personal favorite, but when I was learning I found other places, like blog posts or w3schools (totally unaffiliated with w3c.org) easier

Comment: i understand your logic perfectly, i guess i was complicating myself too much. thank you so much for helping!!!

Comment: @Mr.J Np! Do note that this question has been closed, so it might be deleted after a while. If you want to go back to these answers, I think the question should still be available to you if you search for 'deleted questions' in your profile, after it's deleted